# How to make a PHP time class

Tags: php

I want to make a PHP class that can collect information from the database and checks when that particular operation was performed, based on that it should be able to tell me that the operation was performed 10 minutes ago, or 2 days ago, or 3 years ago, I made a PHP class but sometimes it returns negative time, and I checked and cross checked it did not seem as if anything was wrong, please I need help

```
<?php
class ClassTimeFormat{
    protected $dateTime;

    public function __construct($dateTime){
        $this->dateTime =   $dateTime;
    }

    public function getYears(){
         $sql=  " SELECT YEAR('$this->dateTime') as year";
         $result    =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
         $row   =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());
         return $row['year'];
    }

    public function getDayofMonth(){
        $sql    =   "SELECT DAY('$this->dateTime') as day";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['day'];
    }

    public function getDayofWeek(){
        $sql    =   "SELECT DAYNAME('$this->dateTime') as dayofweek";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['dayofweek'];
    }



    public function getMonthName(){
        $sql    =   "SELECT MONTHNAME('$this->dateTime') as monthname";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['monthname'];
    }

    public function getMonth(){
        $sql    =   "SELECT MONTH('$this->dateTime') as month";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['month'];
    }

    //TIme methods
    public function getSecs(){
        $sql=   " SELECT SECOND('$this->dateTime') as seconds";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['seconds'];
    }

    public function getMins(){
        $sql=   " SELECT MINUTE('$this->dateTime') as minutes";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['minutes'];
    }

    public function getHour(){
         $sql=  " SELECT HOUR('$this->dateTime') as hours";
         $result    =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['hours'];

    }
    public function getSecsDiff(){
        $sql=   " SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(SECOND FROM '$this->dateTime') as seconds;";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['seconds'];
    }

    public function getMinsDiff(){
        $sql=   " SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM '$this->dateTime') as minutes;";
        $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['minutes'];
    }

    public function getHourDiff(){
         $sql=  " SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '$this->dateTime') as hours;";
         $result    =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['hours'];

    }


    public function getExactTime(){
        if(date('Y') > $this->getYears()){
            return (date('Y') - $this->getYears())." Years ago";
        }
        else{
            if($this->getMonth() != date('n')){
                return (date('n') - $this->getMonth())." Months ago";   
            }
            else{
                if($this->getDayofMonth() != date('j')){
                    return (date('j') - $this->getDayofMonth())." Days ago";
                }
                else{
                    if($this->getHour() != date('G')){
                        return (date('j') - $this->getHour())." Hours ago";
                    }
                    else{
                        if($this->getMins() != date('i')){
                            return (date('i') - $this->getMins())." Minutes ago";
                        }
                        else{
                            if($this->getSecs() != date('s')){
                                return (date('s') - $this->getSecs())." Seconds ago";
                            }
                            else{
                                return "Just now";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: you'll need to show us some code if you want us to help you find the bugs.

Comment: No answers until you try something

Comment: also, are you aware that PHP has a built-in `DateTime` class, which is capable of doing what you've described?

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge - that makes no sense. "the textarea wont let me" - it (the textarea) has nothing to do with your php method of calculating elapsed time..

Comment: why does the textarea say my codes are not properly formated, somebody help, been trying to post my codes

Comment: I mean the textarea where I would place the codes I tried out

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge - ahh, gotcha. :) Hard to say what you're doing wrong. Are you wrapping the code with code tags? - You can use the {} button when the text is selected, or you can use the back-tick - not to be confused with `'` - It's the key to the left of the 1/! key on an us-english keyboard.

Comment: @enhzflep, thanks got the codes up now, take a look

Comment: Ouch! My eyes, my eyes. I don't understand why you store so muh data in the database. I suggest you have a look into the Unix Epoch. Basically, all you need to do is store the number of ms that have elapsed since Jan 1 1970 (Thats the number that time() gives you) You can then work out the exact year/month/day/hr/min/sec from the number that time() gives you. I suggest read the help-file for php.  I.e "php_enhanced_en.chm" - get it and other language variants here: http://php.net/download-docs.php. Get the `"HTML Help file (with user notes)"` version.

Comment: @enhzflep, the whole information is just stored in one cell of the table as timestamp, all those information can be collected from the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a class. If your time is negative, you may have subtracted the times the wrong way around.

In this code, $intTime simply comes from time()

```
function makeNiceTime($intTime)
{
     $curTime = time();
     $strTime = '';
     if ( ($curTime-$intTime) <  (60)) //(24*60*60))
     {
        $strTime = sprintf("%d seconds ago", $curTime-$intTime);
     }
     else if ( ($curTime-$intTime) <  (60*60)) //(24*60*60))
     {
        $strTime = sprintf("%d minutes ago", ($curTime-$intTime) / 60 );
     }
     else if ( ($curTime-$intTime) <  (60*60*24)) //(24*60*60))
     {
        $strTime = sprintf("%d hours ago", ($curTime-$intTime) / (60*60) );
     }
     else if ( ($curTime-$intTime) <  (60*60*24*7)) //(24*60*60))
     {
        $strTime = sprintf("%d days ago", ($curTime-$intTime) / (60*60*24) );
     }
     else
     {  // sample: "12.22 am Sat 21-Jul 2012"
        $strTime = date("g.i a D j-M Y", $intTime);
     }
     return $strTime;
}
```